# How are samples selected from training data in Xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, xgboost, sampling

In Random Forest, each tree is not fed with the full batch of training data, only a sample.

How does this work for Xgboost? If this sampling happens as well, how does it work for this ML algorithm?

Comment: I understand that you are asking about the sampling techniques used to train each tree.

Comment: yes, how data is sampled by Xgboost while training the training.

Comment: like in Catboost docs they have mentioned the bootstrap strategy, but I am not very much clear in Xgboost

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Gradient Boosting the simple tree is built for only a randomly selected sub-sample of the full data set (random without replacement).

While on the other hand, Random Forest the samples for each decision tree are selected via [bootstrapping](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-bootstrap-method/); sampling a dataset with replacement.

Particularly for **xgboost** (see paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf))the ratio of sampling of each tree can be modified with the following hyperparameter:

> - subsample [default=1]
>
> Subsample ratio of the training instances. Setting it to 0.5 means that XGBoost would randomly sample half of the training data prior to growing trees. and this will prevent overfitting. Subsampling will occur once in every boosting iteration.

There are more parameters such as colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel, colsample_bynode.

Bootstrapping techniques can vary with the implementation and. Normally I use Catboost implementation for several reasons.

You can read about the sampling of cb that you can use in the documentation [here](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_bootstrap-options.html)

Moreover, a paper that I found interesting a bit ago is [Minimal Variance Sampling in Stochastic Gradient Boosting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13204.pdf) . I will quote one of the sentences from the abstract

> Different sampling approaches were proposed, where probabilities are not uniform, and it is not currently clear which approach is the most effective...it leads
> to a new sampling technique, which we call Minimal Variance Sampling (MVS)...The superiority of the algorithm was confirmed
> by introducing MVS as a new default option for subsampling in CatBoost

Here the Catboost development team explains what is the new sampling technique that is the default in their algorithm.

Comment: N.B., xgboost's subsampling is done _without replacement_, unlike bootstrapping.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks for the correction! :) Let me know if you see something that can be improved, please

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ‘Carlos Mougan,’ and add the comparison with these models.

Basically, GB(Breiman 1996,
1999)、SGB(Friedman
2002) and XGB(Chen and Guestrin
2016) do sampling w/o replacement. GB uses the
full sample set for each iteration. Thus, GB performs like sampling w/o
replacement. So, the three use sampling w/o replacement by tradition.

However, bagging and RF(Breiman 2001) do
sampling w/ replacement. So, the two use sampling w/ replacement by
tradition.

---

There are some discussion between sampling w/ or w/o replacement.
Binder and Schumacher
(2008) run an experiment, model sampling w/o
replacement coverge faster.

LGB(using GOSS, play a role of ‘hard example mining’)(Ke et al.
2017) and CatBoost(using Minimal Variance
Sampling)(Prokhorenkova et al. 2018;
Ibragimov and Gusev 2019) perform sampling
by weights, thus both build the subset over iteration w/ replacement.

---

Binder, Harald, and Martin Schumacher. 2008. “Adapting Prediction Error
Estimates for Biased Complexity Selection in High-Dimensional Bootstrap
Samples.” *Statistical Applications in Genetics and Molecular Biology* 7
(1).

Breiman, Leo. 1996. “Bagging Predictors.” *Machine Learning* 24 (2):
123–40.

———. 1999. “Using Adaptive Bagging to Debias Regressions.” Technical
Report 547, Statistics Dept. UCB.

———. 2001. “Random Forests.” *Machine Learning* 45 (1): 5–32.

Chen, Tianqi, and Carlos Guestrin. 2016. “Xgboost: A Scalable Tree
Boosting System.” In *Proceedings of the 22nd Acm Sigkdd International
Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining*, 785–94.

Friedman, Jerome H. 2002. “Stochastic Gradient Boosting.” *Computational
Statistics & Data Analysis* 38 (4): 367–78.

Ibragimov, Bulat, and Gleb Gusev. 2019. “Minimal Variance Sampling in
Stochastic Gradient Boosting.” *Advances in Neural Information
Processing Systems* 32: 15087–97.

Ke, Guolin, Qi Meng, Thomas Finley, Taifeng Wang, Wei Chen, Weidong Ma,
Qiwei Ye, and Tie-Yan Liu. 2017. “Lightgbm: A Highly Efficient Gradient
Boosting Decision Tree.” *Advances in Neural Information Processing
Systems* 30: 3146–54.

Prokhorenkova, Liudmila Ostroumova, Gleb Gusev, Aleksandr Vorobev, Anna
Veronika Dorogush, and Andrey Gulin. 2018. “CatBoost: Unbiased Boosting
with Categorical Features.” In *NeurIPS*.